# Can a professor be fired for lying about a student breaking the rules?

Tags: employment, education, unemployment

So let's say a professor at a college knowingly lies and tells the administration that a student did something that got the student expelled. Say administration found out the professor lied. Would that professor normally be fired?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because employment decisions of any given institution are not a legal question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "normal" answer. Grounds for firing depends on numerous factors. Some universities have explicit rules and procedures regarding termination, and they depend on the "status" of the person (ask about "tenure" on Academia SE). In principle, a faculty person can be fired because be belched, or wore a business-inappropriate shirt. State-funded universities may have stronger job protections built in to their rule system. I think it is likely that the administration would strongly *want* to fire him, though first they would undo the expulsion (which they can do).

Comment: This said, the conduct in question is not at the core of the conduct protected by tenure or by a fixed term appointment (e.g. a three year assistant professorship). A professor who intentionally seriously assaulted a student could almost always be fired, as could a professor who simply failed to show up to class for an extended period without a good excuse. One who supported a controversial academic position could not be fired although a fixed term post might not be renewed. This fact pattern is probably a close call between those extremes and would happen only with the clearest of proof.